# Can I register local physical SIM number into Twilio platform as an active number?

Tags: ios-simulator

I have local SIM number which used to receive OTP, I need to use Twilio as SMS gateway to automate certain processes within my RPA workflow.

I couldn't find an option to register local SIM number, only the buy new number and it not available for my region/country.